# Qual a diferença entre map() e lenght()?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, map

Eu estava estudando e apareceu este código:

```js
var materials = [
  'Hydrogen',
  'Helium',
  'Lithium',
  'Beryllium'
];

console.log(materials.map(material => material.length));
```

Pelo o que eu entendi, ele varre o array e retorna  outro array com o numero de letras de cada palavra, mas como isso acontece? Se o `map` a função de retornar as ''palavras'' do array e o `lenght` também ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `map` recebe uma função que é aplicada a cada elemento, e o retorno dessa função constrói todos os novos elementos *mapeados*.

A função `map` que indicou poderia ter sido escrita assim (sem *Arrow Functions*):

```js
var materials = ['Hydrogen', 'Helium', 'Lithium', 'Beryllium'];

console.log(
  materials.map(function (material){
    return material.length;
  })
);
```

Assim fica talvez mais claro que o `map` vai pegar em cada `material` e no lugar desse material colocar outro elemento que será o retorno da função passada, neste caso o `.length` do `material`. Sendo cada `material` uma `string` o `.length` vai dar a quantidade de carateres que cada uma tem.

Note que estou a abusar um pouco do português para ficar fácil de perceber, pois o `map` não altera o array original. Apenas devolve um novo com o mapeamento de cada elemento.

Poderia no entanto mapear para qualquer outra coisa que pretendesse, como por exemplo mapear cada material para tudo em maiúsculas:

```js
var materials = ['Hydrogen', 'Helium', 'Lithium', 'Beryllium'];

console.log(
  materials.map(function (material){
    return material.toUpperCase();
  })
);
```

Mesmo utilizando *Arrow Functions* poderia ter o `return`:

```js
var materials = ['Hydrogen', 'Helium', 'Lithium', 'Beryllium'];

console.log(
  materials.map(material => {
    return material.length;
  })
);
```

Mas como o `return` é implícito quando não tem `{}` acaba por ser escrito dessa forma que é mais simples e direto.

Como ultima nota tenha cuidado quando escreve `length` que no seu caso tem um erro ortográfico (escreveu `lenght`) que é muito comum de acontecer.

Answer (score 3):

Então, a função mapa irá percorrer o array e enviará como parâmetro para o callback que você fornecer cada elemento deste array. O retorno dela é um novo array com o retorno do callback que você definiu.

Já a propriedade length apenas te dá o tamanho do array.

```
console.log([1, 2, 3]) // retorna 3, que é  tamanho do array
console.log([1, 2, 3].map(val => val * 2) // retorna um novo array com osvalores 2, 4 e 6
```